# How to block El-Tags in my JAVA tomcat web application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, el, jsp-tags

I've came across the problem of EL (expression-language) injection in my Java Tomcat application.
i have tried to solve it in the web.xml file using:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
         <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

and with the suggestion in the following article:
https://www.aspectsecurity.com/uploads/downloads/2012/12/Remote-Code-with-Expression-Language-Injection.pdf

```
<context-param> 
 <description>Spring Expression Language Support</description> 
 <param-name>springJspExpressionSupport</param-name> 
 <param-value>false</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

However neither of them seem to work.
i have tested it with the following .jsp file:

```
request param is: ${param.name}
```

and typed in the URL:

```
http://<myURL>/<myPath>/test.jsp?name=blablabla
```

the output to the screen was

```
request param is: blablabla
```

while i was expecting it to be:

```
request param is: ${param.name}
```

after my changes.
Any suggestions?

Comment: according to the document the problem is when you have el in your parameter that gets evaluated. the case you show is perfectly normal. and, imo, disabling el completely is just missing out on a lot of useful functionality

Answer (score 0):

Well problem solved. In case someone will run into it the future: 
The solution is to add to the web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
    <!-- Set to true to disable JSP scripting syntax -->
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
    <!-- Set to true to disable Expression Language (EL) syntax -->
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```